# How to set ng2-smart-table button class

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng2-smart-table

I would like to set the button class of the add/delete/edit buttons of my ng2-smart-table to 'btn btn-sm btn-warning'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
settings = {
  add: {
     addButtonContent: '<i class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Add</i>'
  },
  edit: {
     editButtonContent: '<i class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</i>'
  },
  delete: {
     deleteButtonContent: '<i class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Delete</i>'
  }
}
```